# Could not register the assembly System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null - Problem with Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, nuget

I have a problem building a project by error:
Could not register the assembly 'Xamarin.Essentials': System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Xamarin.Essential is NuGet Package:
[Xamarin.Essential Nuget Gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Essentials/)

I did all the recommended cleaning on VS and it still doesn't work. Anyone had a similar problem?

Visual Studio for Mac - version **8.6.5** (build 23)

Xamarin.Essentials - version **1.5.3.2**

Error Visual Studio description:
/Users/.../App.iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT4116: **Could not register the assembly 'Xamarin.Essentials': System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.** (MT4116) (App.iOS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed Visual Studio for Mac and all its dependencies with a script and installed VS with the latest version. Now it is working.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Uninstall Visual Studio for Mac
echo "Uninstalling Visual Studio for Mac..."

sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Visual Studio.app"
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/Visual\ Studio
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Preferences/Xamarin/
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/VisualStudio
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/VisualStudio/7.0/LocalInstall/Addins/

# Uninstall Xamarin.Android
echo "Uninstalling Xamarin.Android..."

sudo rm -rf /Developer/MonoDroid
rm -rf ~/Library/MonoAndroid
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.android.pkg
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Android.framework


# Uninstall Xamarin.iOS
echo "Uninstalling Xamarin.iOS..."

rm -rf ~/Library/MonoTouch
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework
sudo rm -rf /Developer/MonoTouch
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.monotouch.pkg
sudo pkgutil --forget com.xamarin.xamarin-ios-build-host.pkg


# Uninstall Xamarin.Mac
echo "Uninstalling Xamarin.Mac..."

sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework
rm -rf ~/Library/Xamarin.Mac


# Uninstall Workbooks and Inspector
echo "Uninstalling Workbooks and Inspector..."

if [ -f "/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Interactive.framework/Versions/Current/uninstall" ]; then
    sudo /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Interactive.framework/Versions/Current/uninstall
fi


# Uninstall the Visual Studio for Mac Installer
echo "Uninstalling the Visual Studio for Mac Installer..."

rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/XamarinInstaller/
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/VisualStudioInstaller/
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/XamarinInstaller/
rm -rf ~/Library/Logs/VisualStudioInstaller/

# Uninstall the Xamarin Profiler
echo "Uninstalling the Xamarin Profiler..."

sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app"

echo "Finished Uninstallation process."
```

Answer (score 0):

> Could not register the assembly 'Xamarin.Essentials':
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null

**1)** close VS for Mac, delete all nuget caches under `~/.nuget/packages`, `~/.local/share/NuGet/v3-cache` and `~/.local/share/NuGet/plugins-cache`

**2)** delete the whole `bin` and `obj` folder under the project folder and then restart your project again.

**3)** try to uninstall that `Xamarin.Essentials` nuget package and reinstall that package in your project to test again.

**Also**, try the lower version `1.3.1`.

**4)** you can also create a new project and then install that package to test whether the issue still persists in the new project.

Comment: Suggestions for solution 1. 2. and 3. did not help. For 4 I checked 5 earlier versions of Xamarin.Essential and it still doesn't work. I also started a new project and a new error appeared (MTOUCH: Error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log. (MT5202)) so I can't check it. Xamarin Native seems to be dying.

Comment: Or please try to reinstall vs for mac.

Comment: I will try. Thank you.

Comment: Also,before you reinstall vs for mac, you can try to clean your mac os first.